# Xcode - Authentication failed error when adding repository with SSH auth

Tags: xcode, git, ssh, xcode7

I am trying to add repository via Xcode > Settings > Accounts and I am stuck on the proper address. Address of our repo is quite simple: my.domain.com:port/project-name. Authentication via SSH Keys. Could someone help me to understand what's going on here? See screenshot below.

By the way running git clone git+ssh://git@my.domain.com:port/project-name works fine.

[image]

**EDIT**

Running git clone without git+ssh//

```
git clone git@my.domain.cz:2222/project-name
```

or

```
git clone git@my.domain.cz:22/project-name
```

is giving me same error:

> ssh: connect to host my.domain.cz port 22: Connection refused
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Comment: It's not working for 22 even with git clone. Not sure why it's set up like this. Do you think that it matters?

Comment: Yes, The port matters. Give it a try without `git+ssh://`. Just `git@...:port/project`. as per [this article](https://support.codebasehq.com/articles/getting-started/git-and-xcode).

Comment: See edit. Git clone stopped working without that. It seems like it starts ignoring port 2222 and is giving same error about port 22.

Comment: It seems I've figured this out. Xcode is quite happy when you give it ssh://git@my.domain.cz:2222/project-name. Answer this officially and I will accept it since you helped me a lot with your hints. Thanks man.

Comment: What happens when you set-up `~/.ssh/config` for this host?  That's how I would always do it as it allows you to specify port, username and keys and refer to the host with a simple string.

Comment: How can I set it up? These things are not exactly my cup of tea. Removing that 'git+' from URL solved it anyway. That might be just another Xcode bug who knows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xcode accepts just `ssh://git@my.domain.cz:2222/project-name`.

The `git` protocol is somehow redundant in this case. Raw `git` tools don't have a problem with it, but Xcode does not like it for some reason.

Comment: I don't understand the point you are making?  That the port number is important?  I really don't see how that's news to anyone at all.

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes, port number is important in TCP/IP communication. Setting details in `~/.ssh/config` is preferred way, but it might not be read by Xcode. The protocol specification (`git+ssh`) was a problem in the question.

Comment: This is still an issue in Xcode 12.4, and I would add that if you are pushing to a repo on a local server, you need to use the raw IP address as xcode either does not want or cannot read anything from your .ssh/config file

Answer (score 5):

It always fails for me when I use existing ssh keys.
I created a new ssh key pair through Xcode and uploaded the public key to the git server (in my case, Phabricator), and it works.