# Xcode 10.1 push to github using ssh key

Tags: git, ssh-keys, xcode10.1

I had created my ssh keys manually from command line and added to my gihub, gitlab accounts. Everything work fine e.g cloning, pushing, pulling etc using command line and source tree client.

The problem is when I try to push using xcode it gives me error saying that `Authentication failed because the credentials were rejected`. See screenshot

[image]

Please note that Xcode is able to clone the repos using ssh keys but is not able to push(for pushing the changes I either use command line or source tree).

Comment: is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143563/xcode-authentication-failed-error-when-adding-repository-with-ssh-auth

Comment: @rLevv sorry it is not helpful. In the link shared by you the address was specified using `git+ssh` but here as you can clearly see in my screenshot i am using address starting with `git`

Comment: @KhurramShehzad Did you solve?

Comment: @Giorgio not yet

Comment: Also encountering the same problem. Clone, push, pull all work fine on commandline. Public Key is added to Github. Xcode 10 doesn't play nicely.

Answer (score 10):

Create a key with the following command:

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "xxx@yyyy.com" -m PEM`

**Should** add `-m PEM`

Comment: This worked for me. Adding the PEM public key to Github allowed Xcode to integrate successfully. Good catch!

Comment: I had already created the key and added to gihub, gitlab and bitbucket. Why do I need to regenerate it and add again?

Comment: This also fixed the same issue with an on-premise gitlab repo

Comment: Anyone knows why PEM required? It seem to me the PEM is legacy insecure formed and should not be used.

Comment: thank you it worked